# Angular 9 Redirect if query param not provided

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a route that should only be accessible to a user when they click a link from an email and are redirected with a valid query parameter in the url. If the parameter is not provided, I want to redirect to a 404 page not found component, like follows.

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      if (params.myParam) {
        //do something
      } else {
        // redirect to 404
      }
    })
```

The issue I have is that query params is initialized to an empty object in ngOnInit(). I have utilized rjxs to wait until the parameter is accessible like this

```
this.route.queryParamMap.pipe(
      filter(paramMap => paramMap.has('myParam')),
      map(paramMap => paramMap.get('myParam')),
      take(1)
    ).subscribe(myParam => doSomething(myParam));
```

But I'm not very well versed in rxjs operators, and now I'm stuck on how to actually redirect if  paramMap has finished initializing and the parameter isn't found.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "query params is initialized to an empty object in ngOnInit()"? `ngOnInit` within the same component?

Comment: If I subscribe to queryParams in ngOnInit like this, `this.route.queryParams.subscribe(console.log)`, the first time it emits, I see `{}`.

Comment: console out this.route.snapshot.queryParms  and tell me what you see

Comment: @Flightdoc5242 `{}`, using route `localhost:4200/?myParam=464f4e2a-a0fa-4cd8-baf2-a8945cfb2aaf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a problem in many apps, as the params and query params are implemented as behavior subjects, get around this by waiting for the `NavigationEnd` event, where the query params will definitely already be set...

```
   const navEnd$ = this.router.events.pipe(filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd));
   navEnd$.pipe(withLatestFrom(this.route.queryParams)).subscribe(
     ([navEnd, queryParams]) => {
       if (queryParams.myParam) {
         // do the thing
       } else {
         // navigate
       }
     }
   )
```

Comment: glad to help, you can use `combineLatest` instead of `withLatestFrom` to the same effect if you want to capture all query param map changes. or just add your `take`  or `first` operator if you only want 1

Answer (score 0):

In order to route to a `404` if the queryParam is not set, do:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router'

class ...

constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute){
this.route.queryParamMap.pipe(
  skip(1),
  map(paramMap => paramMap.get('myParam')),
  tap(param=>{if(param=={} || param==undefined)this.router.navigateByUrl("/404.html")})
).subscribe(myParam => doSomething(myParam));

}
```

You can start the subscription within the constructor, that way you will get the first value before it is modified in any other methods like ngOninit.

Comment: this will just never emit if the param is excluded?

Comment: It will emit, but we are using a `tap` operator in the `pipe` to  check if the param is set or not and redirecting accordingly.

Comment: you've explicitly filtered anything without the param `myParam`, so if it's excluded, it will never emit. test the code.

Comment: And if the param is not set => the code block inside subscribe won't execute;

Comment: neither will the code inside the tap block. TEST IT

Comment: @bryan60 sorry. I didn't check. Thanks!

Comment: @bryan60 is right, I'm testing it in my app now and it doesn't get past filter if the param isn't included

Comment: This still doesn't work for me. The issue is that when the observable first emits, I receive an empty object. It immediately then emits again, this time with the parameter as key/value. This redirects me to 404, even when I use the correct url `localhost:4200/?myParam=asjdfklaj`

Comment: the edit also doesn't solve the problem, the navigate will always occur, `queryParamMap` is implemented as a behavior subject and emits an initial value that may be empty. it's problematic in many applications.

Comment: @wizloc So, the observable emits twice? first time being empty `{}` and second time either `{}` or some value?

Comment: @wizloc if that's the case, you can use `skip` operator

Comment: Correct. I considered using skip(1), take(1) to skip the first emit, but that doesn't work if there actually is no parameter. It will never have a second emit

Comment: It will now. Please check. You were using `filter` last time;

Comment: still won't work... you skip the initial emit and the subject never emits again if the query params are truly empty, it's a frustrating quirk but the angular team has said it's a necessary one